# Phone unlock patterns using graphs - Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

The problem I am trying to solve is given a `3x3` key lock screen and two integers m and n, where `1 ≤ m ≤ n ≤ 9`, count the total number of unlock patterns of the Android lock screen, which consist of minimum of m keys and maximum n keys.

I am trying to map this problem to a graph problem where my adjacency list represents edges which are invalid or do not constitute to a valid move. I am getting the correct answers for `(1,1) and (1,2) for (1,3)` and others its not what is expected for example `(1,3) is 385`. Is this a flawed approach? if yes, what changes do I need to do to solve it correctly using the adjacency list I have?

The following is my approach:

```
1- Build graph of edges which can't be reached.
2- For minimum keys to be selected to maximum range
    2.1 For each key
        2.1.1 Visit each key keeping pass the information on how many keys are left to select

3- Visited Function
    3.1 Base Case: If no keys are left to process return 1 the path was valid 
    3.2 Set visited flag to true
        3.2.1 Copy all the adjacent nodes which cant be visited to a unordered_set
        3.2.2 For all keys from 1 to 10 if the node is visited or found in the adjacent list continue
        3.2.3 Recur for remaining and return the count


int numberOfPatterns(int m, int n) {
    if(m < 1) return 0;
    vector<bool> visited(9, false);
    vector<vector<int>> graph = { {}, /*graph of nodes which cant be visited */
                                  {3,7,9},
                                  {8},
                                  {1,7,9},
                                  {6},
                                  {},
                                  {4},
                                  {1,3,9},
                                  {2},
                                  {1,3,7}
                                 };
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = m; i <= n; ++i) /*minimum keys to maximum*/
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            count += visit(graph,visited,j,i);  /* visit each key in turn */
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int visit(vector<vector<int>>& graph, vector<bool>& visited, int node, int keys)
{
    if(keys == 1)  return 1;
    if(visited[node]) return 0;

    int count = 0;
    visited[node] = true;
    unordered_set<int> adj(graph[node].begin(), graph[node].end()); /* helps to look up if the node is adjacent */
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if(visited[i] || adj.count(i)) continue; /* invalid move, move on*/
        count += visit(graph,visited,i,keys - 1); /*valid move recur and count */
    }
    visited[node] = false; /*restore state */
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet?  'not what is expected' What did you expect and why?

Comment: @MrSmith42 yes, I did debug and manually also compute the results for the inputs for which the results are correct. As you would be aware it is not the most easiest of tasks to debug recursive programs. I am more intrested in if my approach is correct or not. Perhaps something obvious I have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the missing piece to the puzzle, I stored the edges which cannot be reached, this in no way implies they cannot be reached ever rather if and only if their `Intermediate` nodes has been visited.

The following is the modified version which works as expected

```
int numberOfPatterns(int m, int n) {
    if(m < 1) return 0;
    vector<bool> visited(9, false);

    /* 
        Add which node is blocking it for example to reach 3 I must pass
        through 2 I cannot reach 3 without traversing 2 and so on 7 
        without touching 4.
    */
    vector<vector<pair<int,int>>> graph = { {}, 
                                  {{3,2},{7,4},{9,5}},
                                  {{8,5}},
                                  {{1,2},{7,5},{9,6}},
                                  {{6,5}},
                                  {},
                                  {{4,5}},
                                  {{1,4},{3,5},{9,8}},
                                  {{2,5}},
                                  {{1,5},{3,6},{7,8}}
                                 };

    int count = 0;
    for(int i = m; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 1; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            count += visit(graph,visited,j,i);
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int visit(vector<vector<pair<int,int>>>& graph, vector<bool>& visited, int node, int keys)
{
    if(keys == 1)  return 1;
    if(visited[node]) return 0;

    int count = 0;
    visited[node] = true;

    for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        if(visited[i]) continue;
        vector<pair<int,int>> neighbour = graph[node];

        bool flag = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < neighbour.size(); ++j)
        {
            /*
                If I am visiting an edge which I cant reach directly I need to check 
                if [neighbour[j].second] I have already been at its intermediate
                location
            */
            if(i == neighbour[j].first && !visited[neighbour[j].second])
            {
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (flag) continue;
        count += visit(graph,visited,i,keys - 1);
    }
    visited[node] = false;
    return count;
}
```